# WebLogic error BEA-170019

Tags: deployment, weblogic, war, weblogic12c

I want to do this deploy .war to weblogic. I'll do like this:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/03-DeployApps/deployapps.htm

I have a problem with point 3.) When i started ./startManagedWebLogic.sh i have error:

```
<Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file /home/../user_projects/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/logs/myserver.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> <2015-07-28 13:08:53 CEST> <Warning> <EmbeddedLDAP> <BEA-171520> <Could not obtain an exclusive lock for directory: /home/mkusmierczyk/Pobrane/wls12130/user_projects/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/data/ldap/ldapfiles. Waiting for 10 seconds and then retrying in case the existing WebLogic Server instance is still shutting down.>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same error starting up WebLogic. To resolve the problem, I stopped both the managed server and admin server. Then, deleted the file `EmbeddedLDAP.lok` contained in the `ldapfiles` directory. In your case, `/home/mkusmierczyk/Pobrane/wls12130/user_projects/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/data/ldap/ldapfiles/EmbeddedLDAP.lok`. After deleting the file, I started both the admin and managed server. This fixed the problem for me. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup of this directory:

   ```
   <domain_home>/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap
   ```
2. Restore ldap from a known good backup, or delete ldap directory.
3. Restart weblogic server.